# How to resize image in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

[How to change from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI7Kd.png)

[To this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Zl5n.png)

I want to shorten the width of the image in this carousel, but not the actual red box. How can i do it? I'm at my wits end. I tried every solution on this forum, it doesn't shrink it the way i show it in the picture.

```
    <div class="container box">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- carousel -->
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide"
                data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0"
                        class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img
                            src=""
                            alt="..." />

                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="" alt="..." />

                    </div>
                    <div class="item">

                        <img src="" alt="..." />

                    </div>
                    ...
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic"
                    role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic"
                    role="button" data-slide="next"> <span
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.carousel-inner .item img {
width: 100%; /* or width: 100% !important; */
}
```

Comment: it just extends it further, making superbig.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 .carousel-inner > .item > img {
      width:100%; /* Or try to use important */
      height:auto;
    }
```

A second way to do this:

```
.carousel {
  width:100%; /* Or try to use important */
  height:auto;
}
```

If don't work let me know so I can help

Comment: The first one makes it superbig, [img]https://i.imgur.com/ZcAgqKC.png[/img] , the second one doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried to change de width and height to adjust the image to the size that you want using the first css snippet that I post? If not help you make a codePen  so I can help

Comment: The first one changes the images height when adjusting width:%, and the height:% doesn't even do anything. I dunno why it changes height on width, why?

Comment: the first: when you change the width :% the height is automatic and change automatically to mantain the right size of the image.If you provide us a codePen I can help you

Comment: Yes, it will. Did you tried to change the height values in that CSS?

Comment: The codePen don't work, please, you need to link the css of bootstrap and the js of bootstrap in your codePen

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to resize an image in Bootstrap Carousel:

```
.carousel-inner .item img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer could you please update with what this is fixing and how it is fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it through some inline styling.

```
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img 
      src="images/image.png"
      alt="testImg"
      style="height: 537px"
    />
  </div>
```

I just used Google Chrome inspect elements to get the height of an image I was happy with and styled the problem images, as I only had some images in my carousel that didn't work properly.

-Note-  styling the images like this did also adjust the positions of the indicators correctly in my testing so this shouldn't be a problem with changing the Width as well as the Height if you need.

I did try the other solutions posted here but none seemed to work. So hopefully this will help someone out.